# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get' in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, get, tuples, namedtuple

I have two lists. one of candidates and one of votes received.  I want to sort them descending by votes received. Zipping works fine. When I print the type of the resultant list it comes back as class 'list'.  Next I sort and, bam!, get an `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute get`.  I don't know how to fix this and would appreciate guidance.

```
for i in range(len(uniquecandidate)):
    result = zip(uniquecandidate, votes) # zips two lists together  

result_list = list(result)
print(type(result_list))   # returns <class 'list'>

result_list.sort(key=lambda x: x.get('votes'), reverse=True) #sort by vote number

print(result_list, end='\n\n')
```

[image: Code and Error]

Comment: mistake dict for list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your candidates and votes are stored in a tuple objects, the get() method won't work on them like it would on a dictionary. I recommend switching from

x.get('votes')

to this:

x[1]

This will get index 1 of each tuple (which in your case is the vote count).

Answer (score 3):

`zip` returns a list of tuples; you can sort them by accessing the elements with their index:

```
result_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

if you like to be more explicit, you can use `collections.namedtuple`, and access the element via dot notation on the attribute name:

```
from collections import namedtuple


Poll = namedtuple('Poll', ['candidate', 'numvotes'])

uniquecandidate = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
votes = [3, 4, 7, 1]

poll_results = list(map(Poll, uniquecandidate, votes))
poll_results.sort(key=lambda x: x.numvotes, reverse=True)

print(poll_results)
```

or with `typing.NamedTuple`:

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class Poll(NamedTuple):
    candidate: str
    numvotes: int

uniquecandidate = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
votes = [3, 4, 7, 1]

poll_results = list(map(Poll, uniquecandidate, votes))
poll_results.sort(key=lambda x: x.numvotes, reverse=True)

print(poll_results)
```

#### out:

```
[Poll(candidate='c', numvotes=7), Poll(candidate='b', numvotes=4), Poll(candidate='a', numvotes=3), Poll(candidate='d', numvotes=1)]
```